# Go Dep - sync Gopkg.toml with vendor

Tags: go, dep

Is there a way to create or sync `Gokpkg.toml` with the packages that i import in my `.go` files?
If my `Gopkg.toml` is empty and I run `dep ensure`, it would download all the packages that I import in my code to the `vendor` folder but it won't update the `Gopkg.toml` file.
It came up when I had to migrate a legacy project that didn't use a package manager to using `dep` in the simplest way possible by just creating a `Gopkg.toml` that contains the latest version of all the packages that I already import instead of running `dep ensure -add ...` manually for every package.
Is there such command?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Remove your `Gopkg.toml` file and just run `dep init` and then `dep ensure`. It will create your `Gopkg.toml` file and automatically set all of the dependencies.

Comment: Damnit! this is embarrassing.. Thank you. `dep init` was actually enough.
It still would've been nice if there was a standalone command for syncing `Gopkg.toml` with source code imports because what if I'm not migrating to `dep`? what if I imported some dependencies ad hoc into a project that already uses `dep` because it was the most convenient way and then want to sync my `Gopkg.toml` to include them? Yes, I could delete the `Gopkg.toml` file and run `dep init` again but it's kind of a work around, no? You were very helpful anyway :)

Comment: As far as I know simply running `dep ensure` should actually ensure that your `Gopkg.toml` file is up to date and add all of your new dependencies :)

Comment: See the [documentation on dep ensure](https://golang.github.io/dep/docs/daily-dep.html#basics) for more info on what it does, but this is a good way of thinking about it: When you run `dep ensure`, you basically ask `dep` to "_make sure that my project is in sync: that Gopkg.lock satisfies all the imports in my project, and all the rules in Gopkg.toml, and that vendor/ contains exactly what Gopkg.lock says it should._"

Comment: I though so too but it didn't work, it updates `Gopkg.lock`, it downloads the imports to the `vendor` folder but it doesn't add them to `Gopkg.toml`. Also, in the documentation you just sent, scroll down to the line that starts with `Of course, given this model,`, they explain that you can just add an import in your code and then run `dep ensure` to vendor the imports but they won't append it to `Gopkg.toml`. It's weird, it seems like it was made that way deliberately, I don't understand why.

Comment: Ah that's interesting, I didn't know that! I always assumed that it was added automatically! Thanks for pointing that out! :)